# SQL search on part of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Let's say I have multiple 6 character Alphanumeric strings. `abc123`, `abc231`, `abc456`, `cba123`, `bac231`, and `bac123`.

Basically I want a select statement that can search and list all the `abc` instances.

I just want a select statement that can list all instances with keyword "abc".

Answer (score 4):

Use `LIKE` and wildcards `%`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourfield LIKE '%abc%'
```

Input

```
yourfield
abc123
abc231
abc456
cba123
bac231
bac123
```

Output:

```
yourfield
abc123
abc231
abc456
```

SQL Fiddle:

Comment: @MahmoudGamal See last sentence of the question.

Comment: that did it, wildcards is what i was looking for. Appreciate it.

Comment: If you only want to match values *starting* with 'abc', then a search for `LIKE 'abc%'` will be able to use an index on that column, and possibly be significantly faster, whereas `LIKE '%abc%'` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this way

```
SELECT *
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE field LIKE '%a%' Or field LIKE '%b%' Or field LIKE '%c%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select * from tablename
  where yourfield like 'yourconstantcharacters%'
```

Comment: Yep this was the correct syntax, thanks. Matt called '%' wildcards which was also what I was looking for. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` operator in sql

- Starting With Case

`Select * From Table Where Column LIKE 'abc%';`

- Ending With Case

`Select * From Tablo Where Column Like '%abc';`

- Contains With Case

`Select * From Table Where Column LIKE '%abc%';`

So If you want to use escape character in `LIKE` condition , you must make small changes on your condition

- For Example :

  `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE column LIKE '!%' escape '!';`

More information for you is [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)